# Django admin return to page after save

Tags: django, redirect, admin

I have 3 pages of items listed in my django application admin. After i edit one of them (lets say it is in page 2) and save my changes, i return to page 1 of my listing. How can i make it so i return to the page the item is in?

I looked into some similar questions here at stackoverflow and i believe that i need to use javascript to send a httpresponse with the location header. But how i can determine the page the item is in?

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a code snippet in comments for this django ticket: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3777

Comment: i wish it was possible without middleware but i'll try it, thanks